# messageReactionAdd only detects on cached messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, discord, discord.js

Unfortuantly, I found out that the event `client.on("messageReactionAdd")` only triggeres for reactions on messages, that were written after my discord.js bot went online.
How should I then code a reaction role feature or something else?

I am really stuck rn. After a research I found out about https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/raw-events.md, but still after I copy pasted this in my main file, even cached reactions weren't triggered:

```
client.on('raw', packet => {
    // We don't want this to run on unrelated packets
    if (!['MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD', 'MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE'].includes(packet.t)) return;
    // Grab the channel to check the message from
    const channel = client.channels.get(packet.d.channel_id);
    // There's no need to emit if the message is cached, because the event will fire anyway for that
    if (channel.messages.has(packet.d.message_id)) return;
    // Since we have confirmed the message is not cached, let's fetch it
    channel.fetchMessage(packet.d.message_id).then(message => {
        // Emojis can have identifiers of name:id format, so we have to account for that case as well
        const emoji = packet.d.emoji.id ? `${packet.d.emoji.name}:${packet.d.emoji.id}` : packet.d.emoji.name;
        // This gives us the reaction we need to emit the event properly, in top of the message object
        const reaction = message.reactions.get(emoji);
        // Adds the currently reacting user to the reaction's users collection.
        if (reaction) reaction.users.set(packet.d.user_id, client.users.get(packet.d.user_id));
        // Check which type of event it is before emitting
        if (packet.t === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD') {
            client.emit('messageReactionAdd', reaction, client.users.get(packet.d.user_id));
        }
        if (packet.t === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE') {
            client.emit('messageReactionRemove', reaction, client.users.get(packet.d.user_id));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use message partials to look at messages that were sent before the bot was put online.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });
```

[Source](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages) (i recommend you read)

Comment: This is a good answer but their source is inaccurate for the use of partials and reactions

Using Discord.js v12.2.0 I must create the client with `{ partials: [ "REACTION", "MESSAGE", "USER" ] }` otherwise, the `messageReactionAdd` event fails, with unhandled errors, on uncached messages. Of course, they warn you of these errors but I wanted to point out that their example code does not work